# Display Post Terms and add link

Tags: wordpress, taxonomy, custom-taxonomy

I've created this shortcode to display my terms (custom taxonomy) on specific post (custom post types) :

```
// First we create a function
function list_terms_forme_juridique_taxonomy() {
global $post;
$terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, 'forme_juridique',array('fields' 
=> 'names') );
ob_start();
if( count( $terms) > 0) {  
echo '<ul>';
echo '<li>' . implode( '</li><li>', $terms) . '</li>';
echo '</ul>';
}
return ob_get_clean();
}

// Add a shortcode that executes our function
add_shortcode( 'forme_juridique', 'list_terms_forme_juridique_taxonomy' 
);
```

I am trying to add a link (url) on my terms in order to redirect to the term page but I didn't succeed yet.

Any help ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `get_term_link()`function for this:

```
// First we create a function
function list_terms_forme_juridique_taxonomy() {
global $post;
$terms = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'forme_juridique');
ob_start();
if( count( $terms) > 0) {
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach($terms as $term){
        $term_link = get_term_link($term, 'forme_juridique');

        echo '<li><a href="'. $term_link .'">' . $term->name . '</a></li>';

    }

echo '</ul>';
}
return ob_get_clean();
}

// Add a shortcode that executes our function
add_shortcode( 'forme_juridique', 'list_terms_forme_juridique_taxonomy' 
);
```